# Logs symfony in Mamp

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, phpstorm

I use Mamp to work with Symfony, but I I can not see the logs

For Example

```
public function indexAction () {

    $user = news User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

    return array(
        'formUser' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

In this example I misspelled the `new User()` with `news User()`, but I have a blank page in my browser.
If I do `tail` in log file I can see the error. 
Instead of Mamp, If i Use the symfony server `php  app/console server:run`, I can see the error in my Browser, but I can't use xdebug in PhpStorm (8.0.2)

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: so you want to use xdebug with mamp in phpstorm?

Comment: If I Use Mamp, I can use xdebug in PhpStorm, but I don't see the error of `news` instead the `new`. If I use `php  app/console server:run` I can see this error on my browser `FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 24:
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'User' (T_STRING)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a blank page it means that error repoting is turned off. You can enable it either in php.ini or in your code with the following statement

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I set All Logs in GUI Mamp, In my php.ini I have `error_reporting  =  MAMP_error_reporting_MAMP` and i trying to set `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` in my app_dev.php

Comment: I Moved `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` after `Debug::enable();` and it works. Can I set `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` in my php.ini ? in my php.ini form mamp I have `display_errors = MAMP_display_errors_MAMP` and in Mamp i checked All about logs

Comment: Can I have Got the same GUI of  `PHP's built-in Web Server` http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

Comment: PHP's built-in server has no GUI. Its command line only. But perhaps I'm just not understanding your question ;)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. When I use `PHP's built-in server has no GUI.` I can see the error in my browser, with Symfony Gui instead of "php gui"